# Вопрос освободится ли память из resultset?

Tags: java

Допустим такой фрагмент:

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT StringColumn,IntColumn FROM MyTable");
int i = 0;
Map<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
while (res.next()) {
        Object sCol =
                res.getObject("StringColumn");
        Object iCol =
                res.getObject("IntColumn");
        map.put(sCol, iCol); 
        i++;
        if (i == 1000) {
            process(map);
            map.clear();
            i = 0;
        }
}
```

в MyTable порядка 100 000 000 записей. После выборки первых 1000 записей, они обрабатываются, затем берутся еще 1000 записей и т.д.
После обработки 100 000 записей - память начинает заканчиваться.

Вопрос освободится ли память из resultset'а, занимаемое первыми строками? или на это нельзя надеяться?

Comment: Оно освободится тогда, когда GC придет за ним. Пробовали код запускать? Может GC отработает так, как нужно. А если нет, тогда уж будем думать.

Comment: И думать нечего: если JDBC-драйвер, поставляемой БД не бажный - всё будет ОК.

Comment: глядя на этот пример кода можно надеятся, что resultset будет более оптимально использовать ресурсы чем указаный выше пример

Comment: это пример не рабочий, и никогда им не будет. Единственное что меня волновало, это работа resultset'а

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно надеяться. Но, во-первых, последние записи вы не обработаете. А во-вторых, надо не забывать закрывать его и стейтмент. И да, ещё не помешает указывать тип курсора (FORWARD ONLY): с некоторыми базами данных этот параметр играет роль и влияет как на скорость выполнения запроса, так и на работу с памятью.

Comment: это не рабочий код, просто для примера. Меня беспокоит только resultset